# Entity Framework Many to Many Relation on same entity with additional parameters

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have City entity:

```
public class City
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<CityDistance> CityDistances { get; set; }

    }
```

and i would like to keep distances between cities.
1. How can achieve this in code first entity framework 6?

Here are my other classes:

```
 public class CityDistance
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        public int CityAID { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public int CityBID { get; set; }
        public virtual City CityA { get; set; }
        public virtual City CityB { get; set; }

        public double Distance { get; set; }
    }
```

2. Is this correct design?

When i run "add-migration Distances" here is the result.
3. Why is it adding another foreign key column named "City_ID"?

```
CreateTable(
                "dbo.CityDistances",
                c => new
                    {
                        CityAID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        CityBID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        Distance = c.Double(nullable: false),
                        City_ID = c.Int(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.CityAID, t.CityBID })
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Cities", t => t.City_ID)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Cities", t => t.CityAID, cascadeDelete: true)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Cities", t => t.CityBID, cascadeDelete: true)
                .Index(t => t.CityAID)
                .Index(t => t.CityBID)
                .Index(t => t.City_ID);
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because EF is acting like a simple bookkeeper: `CityA`, `CityB`, that's two foreign keys, `CityDistances`, that's another foreign key, that makes three foreign keys.

EF doesn't know that you intend `CityDistances` to be the other (*inverse*) end of the association for either `CityA` or `CityB`. You have to indicate this explicitly, either by data annotations:

```
public class City
{
    ...

    [InverseProperty("CityA"]
    public virtual ICollection<CityDistance> CityDistances { get; set; }

}
```

or by fluent mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<City>()
            .HasMany(c => c.CityDistances)
            .WithRequired(cd => cd.CityA)
            .HasForeignKey(cd => cd.CityAID);
```

(By which I implicitly say that, yes, this is correct design, at least technically).